# $q not updating when the GET request returns

Tags: javascript, angularjs, promise

I am following [this](http://markdalgleish.com/2013/06/using-promises-in-angularjs-views/) `Angular` tutorial on promises.  I have a service that checks if an array is empty and if so, hits a `REST` service, returns a promise and updates the array.  Here is the relative code:

```
  requestingProviders: [],
  getRequestingProviders: function() {
    var that = this;
    var deferred = $q.defer();
    if(this.requestingProviders.length === 0) {
      this.getResource().search({
        role: 'REQUESTING_PROVIDER'
      }, function(data) {
        that.requestingProviders = data.providers;
        deferred.resolve(data.providers);
      });
      return deferred.promise;
    } else {
      return that.requestingProviders;
    }
  }
```

The `service` is being called from a `controller`.  Here is the code where it is being called:

```
$scope.providers = providerService.getRequestingProviders();
```

The `REST` call is made and returns fine, but the view is never updated.  This is not working like the tutorial explained.  [Here](http://plnkr.co/edit/QBAB0usWXc96TnxqKhuA?p=preview) is a plunker that shows what I am expecting.  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Are you sure that search is succeeding and calling in the anon. function you've passed in?

Comment: Also, I would recommend always returning the promise and then resolving it either with the pre-existing list or with the fetched data. That way callers of your method don't have to look at what they are getting back.

Comment: I know that I my call is succeeding.  How would I return the promise and the resolve it later?

Comment: Instead of linking to a plunker that shows how you'd want things to work, why not attach a plunker with the code you tried with.

Comment: I am showing the code here that I tried.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to resolve your promise:

```
var prom = providerService.getRequestingProviders();

prom.then(function (data) {
   $scope.providers = data;
});
```

Also, change your code to always return the promise:

```
getRequestingProviders: function() {
    var that = this;
    var deferred = $q.defer();
    if(this.requestingProviders.length === 0) {
      this.getResource().search({
        role: 'REQUESTING_PROVIDER'
      }, function(data) {
        that.requestingProviders = data.providers;
        deferred.resolve(data.providers);
      });

    } else {
      deferred.resolve(that.requestingProviders);
    }
    return deferred.promise;
  }
```

Comment: If you look in this [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/QBAB0usWXc96TnxqKhuA?p=preview) that was in the question, angular is supposed to allow you to get rid of the `.then`, but it isn't allowing me to do this here.  Any idea on that?

Comment: Angularjs views can work directly with promises, i.e., you can assign an object in `$scope` to a promise and the view is supposed to be updated when the promise is resolved (see http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.$q under Differences between Q and $q).

Comment: Perhaps that was another version of angular. I changed it to the latest and that did not work anymore. In general, return deferred.promise and then resolve it using '.then'.

Comment: Ah, I see your point... my bad.  Here is the details on angularjs not unwrapping promises anymore: https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/4986